# Pebble.js Clock.Weekday function

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

So, I don't know if I didn't notice before or what but if I use `Clock.weekday` and assign a day and hour and minute that are very close to the current date (today or tomorrow) it works. If I assign to a day two days later than the current date it says `wakeup failed invalid argument` when I try to set up a wakeup with that time (time being `var time = Clock.weekday(blah blah).`..

Am I doing something wrong? or is there a limit with the `clock.weekday` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue with how moment was being used. It is has now been fixed [on master](https://github.com/pebble/pebblejs). Thanks for bringing this up!

[Here is the commit with the fix.](https://github.com/pebble/pebblejs/commit/d65379f168c569209d073f3473ffcdb859f430b7)

Comment: I'm aiming to have pebble.js in a good state for CloudPebble to update to it at the end of the week.

Comment: My pleasure to contribute to pebble.js and pebble!.. What about the sdk? will we have an update on this or something? because I have been usng the SDK to compile and run my apps.

Comment: You simply have to update your local pebble.js git repo and the changes will be applied, barring any merge conflicts with your own changes.